# aperiodic sum of periodic signals

Tags: fourier-transform, decomposition

Asumme that a continous signal is a finite sum of sinusoid. If the signal "begins" at $-\infty$ and "ends" at $\infty$, using Fourier transform, one can find the frequency, the phase and the amplitude of each sinusoid. But if one has only a finite portion of the signal, given as a series  of samples, how to proceed (in e.g. Python) ?  Assuming that the sampling is done at sufficient rate (I guess that Nyquist rate is enough), what is the condition on the size of available portion of the signal so that the characteritics (the frequency, the phase and the aplitude) of each component can be recovered ? Is enough for that size to be greater than the period of the lowest frequency ?

Here is a concrete example

[image]

As the ratio of the two frequencies is irrational, the signal is aperiodic. So, the signal cannot be represented by a Fourier series with a finite number of terms because such a representations yields a periodic signal. Please, correct me if I am wrong, but my conclusions here is that DFT, and in particular FFT, cannot let me recouver the two sinusoids from their sum.

**Is there a method for finding the two sinusoids from the green signal ?**
If so, how can I use the method in Python ?

For completeness, here is the code I used for generating the above plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# need TeX labels
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

# square root of 3
sqrt3 = np.sqrt(3.0)

# a sinusoid
def sinuso1(t: float) -> float:
    return np.sin(2*np.pi*t + np.pi/6)

# another sinusoid with different period
def sinuso2(t: float) -> float:
    return np.cos(2*sqrt3*np.pi*t)

# an aperiodic function as sum of two periodic functions
def sinusum(t: float) -> float: 
    return sinuso1(t) + sinuso2(t)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # sampling step
    step = 0.01
    # 1200 samples
    x = np.arange(0, 12, step)
    # prepare the figure
    fig = plt.figure(dpi=300)
    # plot the 1st sinusoid
    plt.subplot(211)
    plt.plot(x, sinuso1(x), 'C0',
            label=r'\large$\sin(2\pi x + \pi/6)$')
    # plot the 2nd sinusoid
    plt.plot(x, sinuso2(x), 'C1',
            label=r'\large$\cos(2\sqrt{3}x)$')
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor = (0.65, 1.02))
    # plot the sum
    plt.subplot(212)
    plt.plot(x, sinusum(x), 'C2',
            label=r'\large$\sin(2\pi x + \pi/6) + \cos(2\sqrt{3}x)$')
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor = (1, -0.2))
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Why wouldn't FFT work? Time finite signals can be thought of as multiplied by $\text{rect}$ function, which corresponds to convolution with an $\text{si}$ function, so the peaks will be smeared somewhat, bot should still be easy to identify.

Answer (score 1):

From the definition it is clear that computing a DFT of a sinusoid over an interval the length of which is an irrational multiple of the period will lead to a poor result. The most significant component in the frequency domain will yield parameters $A$, $F$ and $\theta$ such that
$$A\cos(2\pi Fx + \theta)$$
is not a good approximation of the input sinusoid. This is illustrated below.[image]

Of course, the result is perfect when a DFT of a sinusoid is computed over an interval the length of which is a natural multiple of the period (see below).[image]

Here is the program for the above experiment.

```
from numpy.typing import ArrayLike
from typing import Tuple
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# need TeX labels
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
from scipy.fft import rfft, rfftfreq


def gcos(freq: float, ampl: float, phase: float, sample_rate: float,
         duration: float) -> Tuple[ArrayLike, ArrayLike]:
    """
    Generates a cosinus wave of frequency <freq>, amplitude <ampl> starting
    at 0 and ending at <duration>, left-shifted by <phase>.

    Parameters
    ----------
    freq : float
        the frequency expressed as number of cycles per time unit.
    ampl : float
        the maxium value the sinusoid takes.
    phase : float
        the angle expressed in radians by wich the sinusoid is
        left-shifted.
    sample_rate : float
        the number of timepoints per time unit (samplig frequency).
    duration : float
        the length of the sinusoid in time units.

    Returns
    -------
    Tuple[ArrayLike, ArrayLike]
        the list of values for abscissa with the corresponding
        list of values for ordinate. These can be directly used
        as the first and the second argument for plotting.
    """
    # Generate sample timepoints.
    x = np.linspace(0, duration, int(sample_rate * duration),
                    endpoint=False)
    # Get the values for timepoints of x.
    y = ampl * np.cos(2 * np.pi * freq * x + phase)
    # Return abscissa and ordinate values.
    return x, y


frequency = np.sqrt(3)
magnitude = 5.0
phase = np.pi/6
print(f"\nInput:\nfrequency: {frequency:.4g},",
      f"magnitude: {magnitude:.4g},",
      f"phase: {phase:.4g}")
SAMPLE_RATE = 100  # Hertz
DURATION = 2.5 # Everyting is fine when DURATION = 3/frequency

# Generate a sine wave
x, y = gcos(frequency, magnitude, phase, SAMPLE_RATE, DURATION)
# Prepare the figure
fig = plt.figure(dpi=300)
# Plot the input sinusoid
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(x, y, 'C0',
#        label=f'\large$5\cos(2\pi\sqrt3 x + \pi/6)$ from $0$ to {DURATION:.4g}')
        label=f'\large$5\cos(2\pi\sqrt3 x + \pi/6)$ from $0$ to $3/\sqrt{3}$')


# Number of samples
N = int(SAMPLE_RATE * DURATION)

# Make the list of frequencies
xf = rfftfreq(N, 1 / SAMPLE_RATE)
# Compute the transform
yf = rfft(y, norm='forward')
modules = np.abs(yf)

# Make the list of indexes
index = list(range(xf.size))
# Sort indexes by corresponding amplitutes starting with the highest one
index.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda i: modules[i])

# Get the highest magnitude, the corresponding frequency and phase.
frequency = xf[index[0]]
magnitude = modules[index[0]]
phase = np.angle(yf[index[0]])
print(f"\nValues found:\nfrequency: {frequency:.4g},",
      f"magnitude: {2*magnitude:.4g},",
      f"phase: {phase:.4g}")

# Check what the corresponding sinusoid is.
x, y = gcos(frequency, 2*magnitude, phase, SAMPLE_RATE,
                            DURATION)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(x, y, 'C1--',
        label=r'reconstruction')
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor = (0.3, 1.02))

# Plot the amplitudes in the frequency domain of the transform.
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(xf, modules, 'C3o', label = 'amplitudes in frequency domain')
# Restrict the plot to <NBCOMP> most significant frequency.
plt.xlim([0, 2*frequency])
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor = (1, -0.2))
plt.show()
```

Can we expect a better result when a continuous Fourier transform is used instead of a DFT? I think we can, although the Fourier integration will not approach a Dirac delta because the values of a sinusoid are given over a finite interval. The following program finds satisfactory values of the frequency and of the phase regardless of whether the interval is an irrational or a rational multiple of the period.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import ArrayLike
from typing import Tuple
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# need TeX labels
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
from scipy import integrate

def gcos(freq: float, ampl: float, phase: float, sample_rate: float,
         duration: float) -> Tuple[ArrayLike, ArrayLike]:
    """
    Generates a cosinus wave of frequency <freq>, amplitude <ampl> starting
    at 0 and ending at <duration>, left-shifted by <phase>.

    Parameters
    ----------
    freq : float
        the frequency expressed as number of cycles per time unit.
    ampl : float
        the maxium value the sinusoid takes.
    phase : float
        the angle expressed in radians by wich the sinusoid is
        left-shifted.
    sample_rate : float
        the number of timepoints per time unit (samplig frequency).
    duration : float
        the length of the sinusoid in time units.

    Returns
    -------
    Tuple[ArrayLike, ArrayLike]
        the list of values for abscissa with the corresponding
        list of values for ordinate. These can be directly used
        as the first and the second argument for plotting.
    """
    # Generate sample timepoints.
    x = np.linspace(0, duration, int(sample_rate * duration),
                    endpoint=False)
    # Get the values for timepoints of x.
    y = ampl * np.cos(2 * np.pi * freq * x + phase)
    # Return abscissa and ordinate values.
    return x, y

def cft(x: ArrayLike, y: ArrayLike,
        factor: int = 100) -> Tuple[ArrayLike, ArrayLike]:
    """
    Numerical computation of continuous Fourier transform of data
    <y> over its domain <x>.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : ArrayLike
        the domain of the data.
    y : ArrayLike
        the data.
    factor : int
        the frequency resolution (precision) is increased by.
        Increases the computation time by the same factor.

    Returns
    -------
    Tuple[ArrayLike, ArrayLike]
        the array of frequencies for which the transform is computed
        and the array of corresponding complex values of the transform.
        The frequencies range from 0 to the half of the sampling
        frequency of the data, stepped by 1/<factor> of the frequency
        of the single oscillation over <x>.
    """
    # The maximum frequency is the half of the sampling frequency, viz.,
    # the number of samples over the half ot the lenght of the abcissa
    # interval.
    maxfreq = y.size / float(2*(x[-1] - x[0]))
    # The mininum frequency corresoponds to 1/<factor> oscillation over
    # the abcissa interval.
    minfreq = 1 / float(factor*(x[-1] - x[0]))
    # Take all frequencies from 0 to maxfreq stepped by minfreq
    frequencies = np.arange(0, maxfreq, minfreq)
    # Create an array where to put the result for each frequency.
    transform = np.zeros(len(frequencies), dtype=complex)    
    # Loop over all frequencies and calculate integral value
    for i, freq in enumerate(frequencies):
        # Compute the Fourier Integral of data y over its domain
        # x for a single frequency freq using Simpson rule. 
        transform[i] = integrate.simps(y*np.exp(-2j*np.pi*freq*x), x=x)
    return frequencies, transform


frequency = np.sqrt(3)
magnitude = 5.0
phase = np.pi/6
print(f"\nInput:\nfrequency: {frequency:.4g},",
      f"magnitude: {magnitude:.4g},",
      f"phase: {phase:.4g}")
SAMPLE_RATE = 100  # Hertz
DURATION = 1.9 # Better whith 2.9 and 1.9.

# Generate a cosine wave
x, y = gcos(frequency, magnitude, phase, SAMPLE_RATE, DURATION)
# Prepare the figure
fig = plt.figure(dpi=300)
# Plot the input sinusoid
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(x, y, 'C0',
        label=f'\large$5\cos(2\pi\sqrt3 x + \pi/6)$ from $0$ to {DURATION:.4g}')

# Compute the continuous Fourier transform. The number of frequencies
# within the fixed range is increased by the factor of 100  (hence the
# frequency resolution is increased by 100). This is the default value
# of the optional <factor> parameter of <cft>.
xf, yf = cft(x, y)
modules = np.abs(yf)

# Make the list of indexes
index = list(range(xf.size))
# Sort indexes by corresponding amplitutes starting with the highest one
index.sort(reverse = True, key=lambda i: modules[i])

# Get the highest magnitude, the corresponding frequency and phase.
frequency = xf[index[0]]
magnitude = modules[index[0]]
phase = np.angle(yf[index[0]])
print(f"\nValues found:\nfrequency: {frequency:.4g},",
      f"magnitude: {magnitude:.4g},",
      f"phase: {phase:.4g}")

# Check what the corresponding sinusoid is.
x, y = gcos(frequency, magnitude, phase, SAMPLE_RATE,
                            DURATION)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(x, y, 'C1--', label='reconstruction')
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor = (0.3, 1.02))

# Plot the amplitudes in the frequency domain of the transform.
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(xf, np.abs(yf), 'C3', label = 'amplitudes in frequency domain')
# Restrict the plot to the most significant frequency.
plt.xlim([0, 2*frequency])
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor = (1, -0.2))
plt.show()
```

However, there is a problem with the amplitude. The error of the amplitude is worsening as the integration interval grows. The next plots are drawn for intervals of size 1.9, 2.9 and 3.9. [image]

[image]

[image]

Could it be due to the integration method (Simpson)? Can this distortion be mitigated using some normalization?

Comment: It turns out that this not a distorsion but the mistake of taking the modulus of the main peak in frequency domain as the amplitude of the the original sinusoid.  The frequency and the phase obtained from the peak are satisfactory  but is there any way to find the amplitude from the transform?  By increasing the interval, one gets closer to Dirac's delta.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is to just estimate the largest frequency component, remove it, and then find the next frequency component.

If I do:

```
plt.plot(np.abs(np.fft.fft(sinusum(x))))
plt.xlim([0,50])
```

then both frequency components are evident, though the irrational one is not sitting nicely on a frequency bin. But that doesn't affect the approach above.

It's not Python, but [here's a previous answer I gave to a very similar question.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/78985/80)

[image: Zoom into frequencies]

Comment: Assuming that i is the index of the maximum in np.abs(np.fft.fft(sinusum(x))), how can I find that the corresponding sinusoid is $a\sin(2\pi ft + \varphi)$ with $a=1$, $f=1$ and $\varphi=\pi/6$ ?

Comment: @Teo See the `removeSinusoid` function on the linked question. You can’t do it from just an integer index (well, you can, but it won’t be accurate because the frequencies are generally not precisely at the index; that’s why `qnf` is used in the linked question).

Comment: Thank you, Peter. I'am hesitating before rewriting your Matlab
code into Python. Can qnf  work for a noisy signal with a big number of sinusoidal compotnents? I'am trying a continous Fourier transform instead, still on a toy example. The result looks better than with DFT but still some problems remain (see the post below).

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with real-world signals and you don't know much about them, to estimate the dominant frequencies the best thing you can do is look at the frequency domain of the signal via an FFT, as long as you do it carefully.

Here are the steps:

1. Choose a [window function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function). All finite length signals are effectively multiplied by a rectangular window. You may want to choose a window (such as  a Hamming window) that has lower sidelobes in the frequency domain.
2. Make sure you have enough data to distinguish between frequencies. Resolution in the frequency domain is inversely proportional to the time length of the signal: $\Delta f = 1/T$, where T is the length of the signal.
3. Once you've made sure you have enough data, and windowed it, take the FFT of it. For your application, I recommend significantly upsampling the FFT by zeropadding it. This will interpolate the frequency domain signal and make it easier to see separate peaks. Doing this does not technically give you more resolution (see step 2 for that), but it makes things easier to see. The FFT function you use should have this built in (e.g., MATLAB: fft(s, N) zeropads the signal out to N samples).

The DFT computes for rational frequencies, so irrational frequencies will straddle frequency bins. Thus, the peak for those frequencies won't show up *exactly* at their true frequencies, but if you zeropad enough it should be very close.